# How to alert when json value is not binding asp web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My client is calling a web api method with a Json model.
But there are some optional fields, and if the client sets these fields in an incorrect format the Web api doesn't throw an error, but just sets the model to null.

How do I know that the model is null, because the optional field is not in an appropriate format ?

```
 //Action
void EnvoieLeadContent(EnvoieLeadInfo leadInfo)


 //Model
 public class EnvoieLeadInfo
 {
        /// <summary>
        /// Date de naissance des enfants
        /// </summary>
        public List<DateTime> DateNaissanceEnfants { get; set; }
```

There are optional children list, but when the date format is not correct, the leadInfo is null, with no exception or ModelState.IsValid = false.

Comment: This is probably what you want http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: @SimonKarlsson Have you a sample with web api ? There are no solution with only asp web api ? Thanks